# Image with border ontop of image in flipview

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

[image: Example]

How would I create the following image example in XAML? ( so a green overlay on top of an image )
When I add an image and a border ( with inside it a textblock ), the border will also always stretch itself to full height instead of the needed height for the text in the textblock.

It's contained in a Flipview. But a normal example in a grid will do also.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the VS2011 / 12 grid application templates.  In Common\StandardStyles.xaml you'll find all the styles for the GridView items on a hub screen, and a lot of them follow this kind of pattern.  For example, the "Standard250x250ItemTemplate" style is defined as follows...

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Standard250x250ItemTemplate">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="250" Height="250">
        <Border Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderRectBrush}">
            <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        </Border>
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundBrush}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayTextBrush}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextStyle}" Height="60" Margin="15,0,15,0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subtitle}" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlaySecondaryTextBrush}" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="15,0,15,10"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: I'm using those on the other screens... one problem though! The text area is defined than! Height is set to 60. My question was how to do this without any height set, so it would take what is needed of the textblock itself. ( but maybe this won't work? )

Comment: You could always try to srt a MaxHeight if removing the explicit height declaration fails.  Not perfect, but better than nothing?